# Change the tittle of labels in a dataframe using Panda Data Reader

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, datareader

I have taken some data from PandaDataReader and printed it in a dataframe. As my work is in Spanish I would like to change the word "Date" in the graphic. I can not rename the columns as from de datareader, the dates are the index, but I dont want to change the index, just the name of the index column. Do you know how could I do it? Here is the code

```
y=data.DataReader('MSFT', 'yahoo', datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 1), datetime.date.today())
df=pd.DataFrame({'Precio de las acciones de Microsoft':y['Adj Close']})
df.plot()
```

And the resulting graphic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqEUZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the index like this:

`df.index.rename('index name', inplace=True)`

Replace 'index name' with whatever you like.